# Get JSON data with jQuery.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get json data with jquery.

I'm using a .html, .js and .json files, shown below:

main.html

```
<input type="button" id="getdata-button" value="Load Data" />
<div id="showdata"></div>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#getdata-button').on('click',function() {
    jQuery.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        //alert('Im here');
        $('#showdata').append("<p>"+data.name+" "+data.email+"</p>");
    });
  });
})
```

data.json

```
{"email": "xxx@email.com", "name": "xyz"}
```

My directory is:

```
  root
     main.html
     js/
       custom.js
       data.json
```

I even tried to put the `data.json` on the the root folder instead of the js folder (I'm in doubt here if the .json file needs to be on the same folder as the `.js` or in the same folder as the `.html` - since I'm using the path just like `"data.json"`). I also put the alert to see if the program is getting till that point but it's not. It gets into the on `'click'` function but doesn't pass through the `getJSON` function.

Any clues why this code doesn't work? I followed some tutorials and some answers here to get to this point but can't get any further.

Comment: If you are loading the page directly from the file system and not via a web server, you might not be allowed to make Ajax calls to the local file system.

Comment: Try `jQuery.getJSON('js/data.json', ...` if you are including the js in `main.html`

Comment: Any errors in the DevTool's console?

Comment: Ran via web server and it worked, thanks

Comment: @Victory is correct. It looks like the path is relative to the main.html, even though getJason is called from custom.js, which is in js directory. It works locally as well on Linux/Mozilla with jQuery 1.7.2. If you want to see the exact code, let me know.

Comment: yet another note - you might have errors with the posted code if use earlier versions of jQuery, so jQuery version is important.

Comment: Can you show the code? I've tested via Windows/Mozilla and it doesn't seem to work as well. So far the only solution was running via web server.